# PHP form submits regardless of required/error handling attempts

Tags: forms, function, required

newbie here

I am currently attempting to build a simple contact form to learn how best to build one. I've tried to make several fields required (name, email, do you like spam radio button). The required html5 element isn't working for me or I am not implementing it correctly based on what i've read here, on google and other places. Likewise the error/require messages don't display if someone attempts to submit a message. Instead the form goes through on submit even if NO content anywhere has been entered. I built this yesterday and have been working on the errors for about 24 hours now and am hoping to find some help here.

I currently am returning no errors, the form sends all information entered as hoped, but it also sends if NO information is entered and that doesn't seem like the best possible form to me. I've tried to build a function to help the required, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Again, i'm new so if my mistakes are obvious and silly, please help em to understand them, that would be greatly appreciated.

[current example can be found here](http://max-o-matic.com/_test2/messageTest2.php)

My code:

```
<!-- For PoohPot -->
 <style TYPE="text/css">
input[type="text"]#website { display: none; }
input#website { display: none; }
.vSmall {font-size: 50%; text-align: center;}
 </style>

 <script>
$('form').submit(function(){
        if ($('input#website').val().length != 0) {
            return false;
        }
});
 </script>


 <?php
//template.php
include '_inc/config.php';//holds arrays, et al.
include '_inc/functions.php';//holds functions that call arrays, etc

include '_inc/head.php';//Begin Document

//include '_inc/header.php';//Begin Content
?>

 <article class="container box style3">
<header>
    <img src="_img/icons/icon_lg-max-o-matic2.png" alt="php icon">
    <h2><a href="index.php"><?=NAME_SITE?></a></h2>
    <p>Spam Survey</p>
</header>

<?php
 $to = "chezshire@gmail.com";
 $subject="Spam Survey";

//----- end conf ----- //

// define variables and set to empty values
 $nameErr = $emailErr = $spamErr = "";
 $userName = $userEmail = $userMessage = $website = "";


 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
  if (empty($_POST["userName"]))
    {$nameErr = "* Name is required";}
  else
    {$name = testInput($_POST["userName"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["userEmail"]))
    {$emailErr = "* Email is required";}
  else
    {$email = testInput($_POST["userEmail"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["spamErr"]))
    {$emailErr = "* You must select an option";}
  else
    {$email = testInput($_POST["userEmail"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {$comment = "";}
  else
    {$comment = testInput($_POST["userMessage"]);}
}


 if(isset($_POST['userName']))
{//data is submitted, show it
//echo $_POST['userName'];

$text = 'From: ' . $_POST['userName'] . PHP_EOL;
//$text .= $_POST['Comments']; //add on to text
$text .= process_post(); // uses proces_post to handle comments and stuff
$from = $_POST['userEmail'];

/*
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
*/

//domain spoofing controls
$headers = 'From: noreply@max-o-matic.com' . PHP_EOL . //from where formhandler sits
   'Reply-To: ' . $from . PHP_EOL . //where replies are to go to
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $text, $headers); //from becomes headers

echo '<div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <p>Thanxs!</p>

                <p>
                    <br /><a href="' .  THIS_PAGE . '">RESET</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </article>
        ';
/*
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
*/

}else{//no data, show form

echo '
    <form action="' .  THIS_PAGE . '" method="post">
        <div class="row half">
            <div class="6u">
                <input type="text" class="text" name="userName" placeholder="Name?" required autofocus />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="6u">
                <input type="text" class="text" name="userEmail" placeholder="Email" required />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row half">
            <div class="6u">
                Do you like spam?<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="Please_Spam_Me" value="YES!" required value="1" />Yes<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="Please_Spam_Me" value="NO!" />No<br />
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $spamErr;?>
            </div>
            <div class="6u">
                How much Spam is too much?<br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-group" class="group-required" id="checkbox-group-id" value="6+" >6 or more<br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-group" value="2+">2 to 5<br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-group" value="Any">ANY<br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--For Winnie the Pooh -->
        <input id="website" name="website" type="text" value"Website" />

        <div class="row half">
            <div class="12u">
                <textarea name="userMessage" placeholder="What is your opinion on Spam?"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><a href="' .  THIS_PAGE . '" class="button form">SEND!</a></li>

                    <input type="submit" />
                </ul>

                <p class="vSmall">
                    * Please note, instead of a reCaptcha I build my own \'honeypot\' from scratch.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</article>
';

}

 function testInput($data)
{
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
}

// this is a function
 function process_post()
{//loop through POST vars and return a single string
$myReturn = ''; //set to initial empty value

foreach($_POST as $varName=> $value)//$_POST is an array

{#loop POST vars to create JS array on the current page - include email
     $strippedVarName = str_replace("_"," ",$varName);#remove underscores
    if(is_array($_POST[$varName]))
     {#checkboxes are arrays, and we need to collapse the array to comma separated string!
         $myReturn .= $strippedVarName . ": " . implode(",",$_POST[$varName]) . PHP_EOL;
     }else{//not an array, create line
         $myReturn .= $strippedVarName . ": " . $value . PHP_EOL;
     }
}
return $myReturn;
}

 include "_inc/footer.php";//End Content/Document
?>
```

Comment: I was doing some testing, and realized that it does work in chrome and firefox, but not safari which is the browser i often use when designing in. So, to clarify, this is't working in safari it seems. I am going to boot up IE and see if it works in IE.

Comment: The requirers are also working in IE too. So its only not working in safari.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use HTML5 stuffs then you need the HTML5 doctype. Place this at the start of your output and see what happens:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Also, typo `value"Website"` should be `value="Website"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the catch. I've correct the 'Website' typo to 'website'. And i am delivering the <!doctype html. via my 'inc/head.php' include ('<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html> <head> <title> <?=$title?> <?=NAME_SITE?></title>... ') Thank you for the suggest, looking for the HTML element was one of the first things i checked. Still, thanks for looking as i'm new and could have easily missed doing that.

Comment: I was googling away trying to look for a solution just now, as i've been doing for a while now and it occurred to me that i am only testing in Safari; I tried it in Chrome and Firefox, the required fields work.

Comment: Supposedly Safari is supported, double check your version. http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-validation-required.html